# Where Condition with like operator

Tags: mongodb, cakephp

I am newer in MongoDB with cakephp.

**Cakephp Code**

```
$conditions = array();
if(isset($this->params->query['search']) && $this->params->query['search']!="")
{
    $conditions['TextBox.name']="/".$this->params->query['search']."/";
}
$data = $this->TextBox->find('all',array(
    'conditions'=>$conditions,
    'order'=>'created_on desc')
);
```

It's equvivalent **MongoDB Query**

```
db.text_boxes.find( {"name":"\/sad\/"}, [] ).sort( [] ).limit( 0 ).skip( 0 ).hint( [] );
```

I want to search following in mongoDB with cakephp.

```
SELECT * FROM TextBox where name like '%sad%';
```

I tried various ways but no luck. Where am I wrong? If more information needed I help you.

Comment: `$conditions['TextBox.name']=new MongoRegex("/".$this->params->query['search']."/");`

Comment: @Sammaye It search as case sensitive I want without case sensitive. how I can do?

Comment: `$conditions['TextBox.name']=new MongoRegex("/".$this->params->query['search']."/i");` with the i flag